# Building settlements in Seafarer

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

Does one have to travel by sea with boats to an island in order to build a settlement? Or can you build a settlement with road or with boat on any turn?

Comment: Welcome to BG.SE! I edited your question to remove the second question. SE is a Q&A site where each Question is just a single question. You can definitely ask a second, separate Question with your other inquiry - just click the "Ask Question" in the upper right.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on land, you can build settlements separated by (at least) two roads.

If you want to go to another island, you should build a "road of" boats from a settlement. Until you reach land where you can build a settlement. From the settlement you can build roads again.

You can build boats along the coast as long as they start at a settlement.

You can not alternate between roads and boats without a settlement in between.

There is one exception. If you have two settlements and you build a road from one and a boat-road from the other, they can connect.

To summarize,

**you can build a boat on an edge if**:

- nothing has been built on that edge
- you have at least one boat in your stock
- you pay a the build cost:

  - a sheep and a wood
  - or a card that enables you to build a ship
- at least one of the hexes is a water hex
- either one of the nodes has a valid connector:

  - the node contains one of your settlements
  - the node contains one of your cities.
  - one of the other edges leading to the node contains one of your boats.
  - the node does not contain an enemy settlement
  - the node does not contain an enemy city

**you can build a road on an edge if**:

- nothing has been built on that edge
- you have at least one road in your stock
- you pay a the build cost:

  - a wood and a clay
  - or a card that enables you to build a road
- at least one of the hexes is a land hex
- either one of the nodes has a valid connector:

  - the node contains one of your settlements
  - the node contains one of your cities.
  - one of the other edges leading to the node contains one of your roads.
  - the node does not contain an enemy settlement
  - the node does not contain an enemy city